# Pass user input from excel cells to an Array

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am very new to VBA, so I apologize if this is a very simple question. I am trying to pass user input data into an array.  Actually, 4 different arrays.  All 4 arrays can have up to 3 elements, but could only need one at any given time.  They are then sorted a specific way via For Loops and then will output the sendkeys function to the active window (which will not be excel when it is running).  I have the for loops figured out and it is sorting the way i need it to. I just need to be able to get the user input into those arrays and then output them to a phantom keyboard (i.e. sendkeys).  I appreciate any help or advice!

FYI, I have declared the arrays as strings and the variables as long... the message boxes are there to just test the sort, they are not very important

```
    For i = 0 To UBound(SheetPosition)
        If j = UBound(Position) Then
            j = 0
        End If
        For j = 0 To UBound(Position)
            If k = UBound(Direction) Then
                k = 0
            End If
            For k = 0 To UBound(Direction)
                If l = UBound(Temper) Then
                    l = 0
                End If
                For l = 0 To UBound(Temper)
                    MsgBox(i)
                    MsgBox(SheetPosition(i))
                    MsgBox(j)
                    MsgBox(Position(j))
                    MsgBox(k)
                    MsgBox(Direction(k))
                    MsgBox(l)
                    MsgBox(Temper(l))

                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `Application.InputBox()` method in two ways:

```
Dim myArray As Variant

myArray = Application.InputBox("List the values in the following format: " & vbCrLf & "{val1, val2, val3, ...}", Type:=64) '<--| this returns an array of 'Variant's

myArray = Split(Application.InputBox("List the values in the following format: " & vbCrLf & "val1, val2, val3, ...", Type:=2), ",") '<--| this returns an array of 'String's
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could get the input from the user using Input boxes:

```
myValue = InputBox("Give me some input")
```

Or forms, which is the preferred method. Unfortunately, forms take some time to develop and are best deployed through Excel add-ins, which also require time to learn how to setup.

Here is a good tutorial on using the SendKeys method:
http://www.contextures.com/excelvbasendkeys.html

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of getting data from cells into an array would be:

```
Dim SheetPosition As Variant
SheetPosition = Range("A1:A3").Value
```

or perhaps

```
Dim SheetPosition As Variant
SheetPosition = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

A few things to note:

1. The array needs to be dimensioned as a `Variant`.
2. The dimension of the array will be rows x columns, so in the first example above `SheetPosition` will be dimensioned `1 To 3, 1 To 1`, and in the second example it might be dimensioned `1 To 5721, 1 To 1` (if the last non-empty cell in column A was `A5721`)
3. If you need to find the dimensions of a multi-dimensioned array, you should use `UBound(SheetPosition, 1)` to find the upper bound of the first dimension and `UBound(SheetPosition, 2)` to find the upper bound of the second dimension.
4. Even if you include `Option Base 0` at the start of your code module, the arrays will still be dimensioned with a lower bound of 1.

---

If you want a single dimensioned array and your user input is in a column, you can use `Application.Transpose` to achieve this:

```
Dim SheetPosition As Variant
SheetPosition = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A3").Value)
```

In this case `SheetPosition` will be dimensioned `1 To 3`.

If you want a single dimensioned array and your user input is in a row, you can still use `Application.Transpose` to achieve this, but you have to use it twice:

```
Dim SheetPosition As Variant
SheetPosition = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:C1").Value))
```

---

FWIW - Your `If` statements in the code in the question are not achieving anything - each of the variables that are being set to 0 are going to be set to 0 by the following `For` statements anyway.  So your existing code could be:

```
For i = LBound(SheetPosition) To UBound(SheetPosition)
    For j = LBound(Position) To UBound(Position)
        For k = LBound(Direction) To UBound(Direction)
            For l = LBound(Temper) To UBound(Temper)
                MsgBox i
                MsgBox SheetPosition(i)
                MsgBox j
                MsgBox Position(j)
                MsgBox k
                MsgBox Direction(k)
                MsgBox l
                MsgBox Temper(l)
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next
```